# How to use tar command options when calling kubectl cp command

Tags: kubernetes, copy, command-line-arguments, kubectl, tar

It seems the `kubectl cp` command uses `tar` command in the background. How can I use (pass them via the `kubectl cp` command) some of `tar` command options such as `--exclude`? For example, this could be helpful to exclude specific files/directories that are not needed to be copied out of the container.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it as -

```
kubectl exec -n <some-namespace> <some-pod> -- tar cf - --exclude='pattern' /tmp/foo | tar xf - -C /tmp/bar
```

As example -

I got a pod running in the namespace "pankaj"; and inside my container i got 2 files at path - /tmp/foo

```
/tmp/foo # ls
file1.txt  file2.txt
```

My use is I want to copy only file file1.txt  so I will be doing it like -

```
kubectl exec -n pankaj <pod name> -- tar cf - --exclude='file2.txt' tmp/foo | tar xf - -C /Users/pa357856/test
```

the result will be I will get only file1.txt

```
$ pwd
/Users/pa357856/test
$ ls tmp/foo/
file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it would be good to have this as part of the `kubectl cp` options too.